# Connecting to MySQL database from Java application using Docker

Tags: java, mysql, docker, jdbc, dockerfile

I am new to Docker. I want my Java application to connect with MySQL database.
I have the following code:

```
    import java.sql.*;  
    class HelloDbDocker{  
    private static String jdbcDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        private static String dbName = "employee";
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
            Class.forName(jdbcDriver);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?user=root&password=");
            Statement s = conn.createStatement();
            int Result = s.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE "+dbName);
            System.out.println(Result );
} catch(Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e);
}
        }
    }
```

For the above code, I want to create a Dockerfile which provide all the dependencies and using that Dockerfile I can create an image which can run anywhere and show the value of result variable on screen.

Comment: do you mean java application and mysql in one docker image?

Comment: You don't include dependencies like Database in Dockerfile. You need to look into docker compose. https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: Actually, I have to set Classpath and add mysql-connector.jar in /jre/lib/ext folder using the dockerfile to run the application. How can I achieve it?

Comment: @MeenakshiKumari, can paste the Dockerfile, it helps to anser your question

Comment: FROM java:8  
COPY . C:\var\www\java  
WORKDIR C:\var\www\java
RUN javac HelloDbDocker.java  
CMD ["java", "HelloDbDocker"] The above lines are in the docker file and following error is displayed after i run the image.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver